# Reference Conf File within Conf File or Apply Rule to All Listening RSyslog Ports

Tags: rsyslog

We have a number of individual conf files with their own ruleset that's bound to its unique port. We want to create a single conf file that will filter/drop specific things such as, if msg from IP drop it or if msg contains x drop it. And have the drop filtering apply to all listening ports. Is this possible to do? Should we avoid using rulesets?

We're trying to avoid updating the drop/filter in each conf file for each port every time the filter has a new update.

Would anyone happen to know if one of the following things is possible with RSyslog?

1. Have 1 conf file that will listen on all rsyslog ports and be processed first? Without specifying each open port.
2. Have a conf file that calls another file with a rule in it?

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Perhaps you could extend your question with a **short example** of what you have to do now, and how you imagine it should be possible to do simpler. Yes, you can include another conf file from a conf file, see [legacy syntax](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/global/options/rsconf1_includeconfig.html) and [rainerscript syntax](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/include.html).

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully that clears it up. Basically I want to create one file that has all the rules to drop events. Currently we have the same rule in every conf file that listens on its own port. Just trying to simplify things to one location.

Comment: I created another question with specific conf examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403599/multiple-inputs-for-single-rule-set-filtering-dropping-in-a-single-location

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the default configuration file, say `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, will contain a line near the start saying something like

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

or the equivalent RainerScript syntax

```
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf")
```

If not you can add it.
This will include all files matching the glob pattern, in alphabetical order. So you can optionally put any configuration in that directory, for example in arbitrarily named files `00-some.conf`, and `10-somemore.conf` and so on.
One file could have lots of `input()` statements like:

```
module(load="imtcp" MaxSessions="500")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
input(type="imtcp" port="10514")
input(type="imtcp" port="20514")
```

assuming you are expecting to receive incoming tcp connections from remote
clients. See [imtcp](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imtcp.html).

All the data from those remotes will be affected by any following rules.
For example, the last included file in the directory could hold lines like:

```
if ($msg contains "Password: ") then stop
if ($msg startswith "Debug") then stop
if ($hostname startswith "test") then stop
```

These will stop further processing of any matching input messages, effectively
deleting them.

---

The above inputs are all collected into *a single global input queue*.
All the `if` rules are applied to all the messages from that queue.

If you want to, you can partition some of the inputs into a new queue,
and write rules that will only apply to that new independent queue. The rest of the
configuration will know nothing about this new queue and rules.

This is called a **ruleset**. See
[here](https://www.rsyslog.com/newbie-guide-to-rsyslog/) and
[here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/concepts/multi_ruleset.html).
For example, you can have a ruleset called "myrules". Move one or more
inputs into the ruleset by adding the extra option:

```
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="myrules")
input(type="imtcp" port="10514" ruleset="myrules")
```

Move the rules to apply to that queue into a ruleset definition:

```
ruleset(name="myrules"){
 if ($msg contains "Password: ") then stop
 if ($msg startswith "Debug") then stop
 *.* /var/log/mylogfile
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I updated my question to be more specific. In the scenario you describe, if we have a file that's alphabetically first that says for all of these ports where you see X drop it. And then we can have other files after that for each port with it's own logging destinations and that should work?

Comment: I've added some more alternatives to my answer, after the horizontal dividing line. I can't guess further until you provide concrete examples in your question. Try something, and post a new question with that code if it didn't work as you expected.

Comment: I'm learning so much, thank you. So in my scenario I don't have access to "/etc/rsyslog.conf", but can create other conf files. Also, for each conf file that was created for each port, they each of their own ruleset. So are you saying I could just create a new conf file that doesn't use a rule set, make sure it's the last processed file, doesn't bind to any inputs, and just say if ($msg contains "BLAH" ) then stop... and that will drop any message with BLAH that comes in on any of the ports specified in all of the other conf files?

Comment: Yes, but with no rulesets, the rules to drop messages will also be applied to the usual inputs in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, so you might be deleting local messages that would normally go into `/var/log/messages`, for example. The preferred way to be independent  of the main config is to use the *same* ruleset name for all your added conf files, and remove all the rules inside the old rulesets. Since the rules are all the same, you just need one file defining that named ruleset.

Comment: Okay this is helpful. Since I'll create multiple conf files all using the same rule set, but different ports. Would I have the input(type="imptcp" port="500" ruleset="rsyslog_master") line within the ruleset of each conf file and before I set variables and configure the action() line? or keep it outside and after the ruleset section/block?

Comment: Are you saying I can bind to multiple ports within a single ruleset?