# Multiple Inputs for Single Rule Set (Filtering/dropping in a single location)

Tags: rsyslog

We're attempting to apply a single filter "0_MasterFilter.conf" to filter/drop all messages with certain IP's and hostnames coming in on ALL configured listening ports, in a single location, in order to reduce administrative overhead.

We're attempting to use a single ruleset "rsyslog_rules" only. Then have multiple inputs for all of the different listening ports. Will the following work? Or is there a better way?

**0_MasterFilter.conf**

```
ruleset (name=rsyslog_rules) {
    if $fromhost starts with 'bilbo' or $fromhost-ip == '0.1.1.1' then { stop }
}
```

**1_Port514.conf**

```
ruleset (name=rsyslog_rules) {
    if $fromhost starts with 'testbox' or $fromhost-ip == '0.2.2.2' then { stop }
    set $!dev='syslog_server'
    set $!loc='net1'
    action (type="omfile" dynafile="514_serverX")
}
input (type="imptcp" port="514" ruleset="rsyslog_rules")
input (type="impudp" port="514" ruleset="rsyslog_rules")
```

**2_Port600.conf**

```
ruleset (name=rsyslog_rules) {
    if $fromhost starts with 'lost' or $fromhost-ip == '0.3.3.3' then { stop }
    set $!dev='dum_machine'
    set $!loc='backroom'
    action (type="omfile" dynafile="600_test")
}
input (type="imptcp" port="600" ruleset="rsyslog_rules")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a ruleset more than once, so `ruleset(name="rsyslog_rules"){...}` can only appear once. Note that the name must be in quotes. Also `starts with` is one word. Do a syntax check with `rsyslogd -N1 -f myconfig.conf`.

---

If you want to have a set of rules that apply to all inputs, but also have
individual rules that only apply to some of the inputs, then you can put
all the common rules in one ruleset, and bind a new independent ruleset to
each input, but **call** the common ruleset from these independent rulesets.
For example:

**0_MasterFilter.conf**

```
ruleset (name="rsyslog_rules") {
    if $fromhost starts with 'bilbo' or $fromhost-ip == '0.1.1.1' then { stop }
}
```

**1_Port514.conf**

```
ruleset (name="special1") {
    call rsyslog_rules
    if $fromhost starts with 'testbox' or $fromhost-ip == '0.2.2.2' then { stop }
    set $!dev='syslog_server'
    set $!loc='net1'
    action (type="omfile" dynafile="514_serverX")
}
input (type="imptcp" port="514" ruleset="special1")
input (type="impudp" port="514" ruleset="special1")
```

The `call` command can be given anywhere in a ruleset. Note that the name
is *not* put in quotes ("").

Comment: Thank you. How can I accomplish what I'm after? Is it possible to bind to multiple ports within a single ruleset? If so, what would be the order in the config when I use the input... to bind but for each port they have their own filter as well as other variables.

Comment: I added some more to my answer, in the hope that it is what you are looking for.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you so much for all you wrote up here, learned so much!

Comment: Note that if you appreciate an answer which allows progress with a problem or provides you with information, even if it is incomplete, you can click on the upvote button. This is independent of the tick of acceptance for your own questions.